# Calling a method that requires an event passed to it - without passing an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following on from previous questions about deferred, I'm trying to set it up.

The following gets files that are dropped:

```
p._initEvents = function() {

    $(window).on('drop', this.onDrop.bind(this)).on('dragover', this.onDragOver);
};

p.onDrop = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    return dfd.promise();
};
```

The deferred is returned to my main class via:

```
var FileDrop = function() {
    this.init();

    return this.onDrop(???);

};
```

But what should I pass to the onDrop method? I get errors if I pass nothing and errors if I just pass 'event': 'Cannot read property 'dataTransfer' of undefined'

Comment: Given that the function is designed to work with an event (by grabbing the `files` sub property) what behaviour are you expecting if no event is passed?

Comment: How can I get it to work with deferred then?

Comment: If you just want the deferred, why not create it directly in FileDrop function?

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: I've posted a possible answer. But I must say that the code in `onDrop` event handler doesn't make any sense. Except for the `deferred` part it only sets a variable `files` which is not accessible from anywhere else than this handler anyway. I'm skipping the `preventDefault` part since you claim that you don't want the event. It's really hard to say what you really want.

Comment: No that's fine. I've deleted some of the code in there to make the example easier to read. I'll just resolve the promise and pass the files like: dfd.resolve(files);

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is this:

```
var FileDrop = function() {
    this.init();
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    return dfd.promise();
};
```

Other two calls which involve `e` in posted event handler will not work without the event.

Comment: Do you have a solution that would work for multiple file drops. At the minute, the promise is resolved as soon as the files are dropped, but if the user drops another set of files, nothing happens, is there a way to 'refresh' a promise?